# BroadcastReceiver and screen off

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, fragment, screen

I have a service that sends a message when it been destroy to a BroadcastReceiver declared in a Fragment.

When the screen is on everything works fine , but if the screen turns off the service sends the message to broadcast, but never receives it

[My code](http://pastebin.com/kHWhmrXn)

Thanks!

Comment: Try to acquire `WAKE_LOCK` in your `Service` as it may sleep during screen-off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not unregistering it on your onpause() method

Comment: Cool. You can mark it as the correct answer so others can find it.

Comment: Also, you will probably need to unregister your receiver somewhere else. That's depends on your code's logic but the ondestroy method might be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can unregister it in onDestroy() method. And also consider using [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to register for and send broadcasts in case you are working within one process.